# Deleting all tables with similar names using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I have created many tables using Python and want to delete all tables with similar names. For example, I need to delete all tables ending with "level1", "level2" and until "level7". Also, I need to delete all tables ending with "_Merge". Here is the screenshot of my table list.

[image]

I write scripts using "ListTables" and then use for loop to delete them one by one. Here is my code:

```
levelfiles = arcpy.ListTables("level*")

for levelfile in levelfiles:

    arcpy.Delete_management(levelfile)
#################################################
mergefiles = arcpy.listTables("_Merge")

for mergefile in mergefiles:

    arcpy.Delete_management(mergefile)
```

But this does not work. Could anyone offer some suggestions about deleting these files?

Comment: Before **ever** using `Delete_management()` you should ***always*** validate the parameter contents with a `print` or `arcpy.AddMessage`.  If you did this, you would see that your wildcards aren't matching.

Comment: @Vince, thanks for your reply. Do you know how to refer to files including the same words? As the question indicated, how to refer to all tables ending with level1, level2 and so on?

Comment: Since you've tried "level*", did you try "*level*"? Personally, I hate double-widcards and would use an `if` in the `for`.

Comment: Try `"*level*"` and `"*_Merge"`.

Comment: Yeah, like this ^^^, without the SE reformatting issue.

Comment: What were the precise symptoms/errors that you experienced to conclude that it "does not work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `"*level*"` and `"*_Merge"` for your wildcard parameter values.

Alternatively, don't include a wildcard at all, but use an `if`, something like:

```
for theTable in arcpy.ListTables():
    if theTable[-6:-1] == "level" or theTable[-6:] == "_Merge":
        print "Deleting:  {}".format(theTable)
        arcpy.Delete_management(theTable)
```

I would comment out that `arcpy.Delete_management()` line initially, and see what it says it's going to delete.  Once the output looks right, uncomment the line and run it again.

This is a little safer as it's more precise about where in the table name the 'level' should appear.

Comment: thanks for your help and this is what I need. Could you explain the meaning of "theTable[-6:-1]"? Maybe I can use your codes for another case. @Son of a Beach

Comment: The square bracket notation is the standard python mechanism for extracting one element (no ':') or a 'slice' of multiple elements (with ':') from an interable object such as a list, or in this case a string.  Think of a string as being a list of characters.  The first character is at index '0'.  The last character is at index '-1'.  (You can count the characters either from the start, or using '-' (minus) to count backwards from the end).  Full explanation at:  https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/ .  [-6:-1] means the 6th last char to before the last char.

Answer (score 1):

First little issue I see is that your second `arcpy.ListTables` is not capitalized right (you have `arcpy.listTables`). Python is case-sensitive, so this is important.

Secondly, `arcpy.ListTables` only searches in the current workspace. So before you search for the files, you need to tell it where to look by adjusting the workspace variable to the location where your tables are:

`arcpy.env.workspace = r'c:\path\to\tables'`

*On a related note, your version of ArcMap (and Python) are very outdated - you should consider updating to something more recent and still supported if possible.*